# FeatureCollection (Error) Array: Max (NaN) cannot be less than min (NaN)

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, land-classification, image-classification, image-segmentation

I am trying to do Object base Image classification, but my code giving me this error, I tried to fix it but nothing worked.
This is an error, "FeatureCollection (Error)
Array: Max (NaN) cannot be less than min (NaN)."

This Part of the code gives me this error,

```
var training_data = SNIC
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: training_points, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
    scale: 30
  })
  .filter(ee.Filter.neq('LC', null));

print(training_data);
```

My Code Link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/7d124b2f94bc4ff0f6af75a2e7740a6d

My whole code is given below,

```
var combined_image = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
.select('B2','B3','B4','B8','B11')
.mean()
.clip(geometry);
//print(combined_image);
Map.addLayer(geometry);
Map.addLayer(combined_image,{min:0,max:0.8,gamma:1.4,bands:['B4','B3','B2']}, 'Sentinel 2 ');
Map.centerObject(geometry);


var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(20);

var SNIC = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: combined_image,
  compactness: 0, 
  connectivity: 8,
  neighborhoodSize: 512,
  seeds: seeds}).reproject({
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 10
});

// Cluster 

var clusters = SNIC.select('clusters');
//Map.addLayer(clusters.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'Clusters');

// Compute the standard deviation of each cluster.
var stdDev = combined_image.addBands(clusters).reduceConnectedComponents({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  labelBand: 'clusters',
  maxSize: 512,
});
//Map.addLayer(stdDev, {min: 0, max: .1}, 'Std dev');


// Compute the perimeter of each cluster.
var minMax = clusters.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
  kernel: ee.Kernel.square(1)
});
var perimeterPixels = minMax.select(0).neq(minMax.select(1));
var perimeter = perimeterPixels
  .addBands(clusters).reduceConnectedComponents({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    labelBand: 'clusters',
    maxSize: 512,
  });
//Map.addLayer(perimeter, {min: 0, max: 1000}, 'Perimeter');
var objectPropertiesImage2 = ee.Image.cat([
  SNIC,
  stdDev,
  perimeter,
  ]);

//glcm

var gray_image = combined_image.expression("((0.3*NIR)+(0.59*Red)+(0.11*Green))", {NIR: combined_image.select('B8'), Red:combined_image.select('B4'), Green: combined_image.select('B3')});
gray_image = gray_image.toInt();
var glcm = gray_image.glcmTexture ({size: 4});

Map.addLayer (glcm);

var arrays = glcm.toArray();
//pca
function PCA(maskedImage){
  var image = maskedImage.unmask();
  var scale = 20;
  var region = geometry;
  var bandNames = image.bandNames();
  // Mean center the data to enable a faster covariance reducer
  // and an SD stretch of the principal components.
  var meanDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 16
  });
  var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
  var centered = image.subtract(means);
  // This helper function returns a list of new band names.
  var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
    var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length());
    return seq.map(function(b) {
      return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
    });
  };
  // This function accepts mean centered imagery, a scale and
  // a region in which to perform the analysis.  It returns the
  // Principal Components (PC) in the region as a new image.
  var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region) {
    // Collapse the bands of the image into a 1D array per pixel.
    var arrays = centered.toArray();
    
    // Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
    var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      bestEffort: true,
     tileScale: 16
    });

    // Get the 'array' covariance result and cast to an array.
    // This represents the band-to-band covariance within the region.
    var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

    // Perform an eigen analysis and slice apart the values and vectors.
    var eigens = covarArray.eigen();

    // This is a P-length vector of Eigenvalues.
    var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
    
    // Compute Percentage Variance of each component
    var eigenValuesList = eigenValues.toList().flatten();
    var total = eigenValuesList.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
    var percentageVariance = eigenValuesList.map(function(item) {
      return (ee.Number(item).divide(total)).multiply(100).format('%.2f');
    });
    // This will allow us to decide how many components capture
    // most of the variance in the input
    //print('Percentage Variance of Each Component', percentageVariance);
    // This is a PxP matrix with eigenvectors in rows.
    var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);
    // Convert the array image to 2D arrays for matrix computations.
    var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);

    // Left multiply the image array by the matrix of eigenvectors.
    var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);

    // Turn the square roots of the Eigenvalues into a P-band image.
    var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
      .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);

    // Turn the PCs into a P-band image, normalized by SD.
    return principalComponents
      // Throw out an an unneeded dimension, [[]] -> [].
      .arrayProject([0])
      // Make the one band array image a multi-band image, [] -> image.
      .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
      // Normalize the PCs by their SDs.
      .divide(sdImage);
  };
  var pcImage = getPrincipalComponents(centered, scale, region);
  return pcImage.mask(maskedImage.mask());
}
var pca = PCA(glcm).select(['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3']);
//print (pca);
//SNIC
var SNIC = SNIC.addBands(pca);
//print (SNIC);

//Map.addLayer(pca);
//Map.addLayer(SNIC,{min: 0, max: 1000}, 'SNIC');
//Raster to Vector
var vectors = clusters.reduceToVectors({
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  scale: 1,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  geometry: geometry,
});
var empty = ee.Image().byte();


var outline = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: vectors,
  color: 1,
  width: 1
});
//Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'segments');

//classification
var training_points = roads.merge(builtup).merge(vegetation).merge(bareland);
//print (training_points);
var training_data = SNIC
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: training_points, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
    scale: 30
  })
  .filter(ee.Filter.neq('LC', null));

print(training_data);


//Create an SVM classifier with custom parameters.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50);
  //{
 // kernelType: 'RBF',
//  gamma: 0.5,
 // cost: 10
//});

// Train the classifier.
var classifier = classifier.train({
  features:training_data,
  classProperty: 'LC',
 inputProperties:  ['B11_mean', 'B2_mean', 'B3_mean', 'B4_1_mean', 'B4_mean', 'nd_1_mean', 'nd_2_mean', 'nd_mean', 'pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3']
  
});

print (classifier);
// Classify the image.
var classified = SNIC.classify(classifier);

Map.addLayer (classified, {palette:["0049bf", "07c46f", "ddd60b", "c91700"], min: 0, max:4});
//Merge into one FeatureCollection
var valNames = vroads.merge(vbuiltup).merge(vvegetation).merge(vbareland);
var validation = classified.sampleRegions({
  collection: valNames,
  properties: ['LC'],
  scale: 30,
});
print(validation);


//Compare the landcover of your validation data against the classification result
var testAccuracy = validation.errorMatrix('LC', 'classification');
//Print the error matrix to the console
print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
//Print the overall accuracy to the console
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
//Save image to Assest
Export.image.toAsset({
  description: 'classified',
  image: SNIC.classify(classifier),
  region: geometry,
  scale: 5,
});

var projection = combined_image.select('B2').projection().getInfo();
//Save Image to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified,
  description: 'classified',
  crs: projection.crs,
  crsTransform: projection.transform,
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }, // Increase the tileScale value
});


//Calculate Area
var all_classes_area = ee.Image.pixelArea()
  .addBands(classified)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'classification'
    }), 
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 1000,
    bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 16 // Adjust the tileScale value as needed
  });

print(all_classes_area, 'All Classes Area in Square KM');

var igbpPalette = [
  '0000FF', // Roads
  'FF0000', // Urban
  '008000', // Vegetation
  'FFFF00', // Bare land
];

// Chart
var area_chart = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
  image: ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classified).divide(1e6), 
  classBand: 'classification', 
  region: geometry, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  scale: 1000, 
}).setSeriesNames(ee.List(['Roads','Builtup Area','Vegetation','Bareland']));
area_chart.setOptions({
  title: 'Area Chart',
  colors: igbpPalette
});

print(area_chart);


// set position of panel
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '8px 15px'
  }
});
// Create legend title
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'Classification',
  style: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '18px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
    }
});
// Add the title to the panel
legend.add(legendTitle);
// Creates and styles 1 row of the legend.
var makeRow = function(color, name) {
 
      // Create the label that is actually the colored box.
      var colorBox = ui.Label({
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#' + color,
          // Use padding to give the box height and width.
          padding: '8px',
          margin: '0 0 4px 0'
        }
      });
 
      // Create the label filled with the description text.
      var description = ui.Label({
        value: name,
        style: {margin: '0 0 4px 6px'}
      });
 
      // return the panel
      return ui.Panel({
        widgets: [colorBox, description],
        layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
      });
};
 
//  Palette with the colors
var palette =['FF0000','008000','FFFF00','0000FF'];
 
// name of the legend
var names = ['Roads','BuiltUp Area','Vegetation', 'BareLand'];
 
// Add color and and names
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  legend.add(makeRow(palette[i], names[i]));
  }  
 
// add legend to map (alternatively you can also print the legend to the console)
Map.add(legend);

// Create the title label.
var title = ui.Label('Land Cover Landuse Classification Map of Margalla');
title.style().set('position', 'top-center');
Map.add(title);
```

Comment: The NaN comes from negative `eigenValues` which you take the square root of. I unfortunately have no idea how you best deal with that.